# Kernel SVM overfitting after training set extension

Tags: svm, kernel-trick, overfitting

I am training Kernel SVM from sklearn package for binary classification problem. 
I perform a gridsearch for parameters optimization. Parameters are taken from following ranges: 'C':[1., 10., 100.], 'gamma':[1e-5, 1e-4, 1e-3].

With larger training set (180k vs 90k samples) I have more overfitting. 
Is it possible? What could cause that effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess the parameters you end up with are $C=1$ and/or $\gamma=1e-5$, which are the ones that yield the least complex model. Those hyperparameters can be suboptimal for you.

The misclassification penalty ($C$) is a function of training set size. In your case, $C$ is probably too large which leads to overfitting. You need a larger search grid or (better) you should use [optimization software to automatically  find suitable hyperparameters](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.1114.pdf). Grid search is pretty bad, even though it is so common. Your search grid is way too coarse to find good parameters.